# Code::Blocks 16.01 Build Failed

Tags: compiling, code-blocks

I am using 18.04.4 lts version of Ubuntu. I downloaded Code::Blocks from "Ubuntu Software" and didn't install any other package. I do not know if the packages required for development are installed.
This error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Hello (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 obj/Debug/main.o||No such file or directory|
||error: no input files|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Please provide more information about you build environment: Which version of Ubuntu, died you install all required development packages for that build. Die you configure the project?

Comment: I am using 18.04 lts version of Ubuntu. I downloaded Code::Blocks from "Ubuntu Software" and didn't install any other package. I do not know what packages are required for development, I am an amateur user yet. "Die you configure the project?" > sorry, i didn't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Ubuntu version was 18.04.4 lts

Comment: Please edit your question and add the new information in the question.

Comment: The file path references, such as: obj\Debug\main.o are giving an absolute path. What you probably want is: `.\obj\Debug\main.o` so you get a relative path based on the current directory. Your Code::Blocks and gcc installations in Ubuntu 18.04 seem to be OK for C programming language, but please note that for C++ you also need to install g++ package with `sudo apt install g++`

Comment: Thank you, i will check after that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a long an details description on the code blocks wiki: [Install Code Blocks from source on Linux](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Code::Blocks_from_source_on_Linux)

The process is not trivial and requires several steps before building the project with:

1. Read the wiki [entry](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Installing_Code::Blocks_from_source_on_Linux) and follow the steps carefully
2. [Download](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/25) or [checkout](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/7) the source code
3. Bootstrap, configure, and make code blocks

   ```bsh
   $  ./bootstrap
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   ```
4. Use checkinstall, to generate and install a Debian package.

   ```bsh
   $ sudo checkinstall
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't follow your suggestions. As I said, I'm new and the steps look complicated so I deleted Ubuntu and installed it again. This time there was no problem when I downloaded Code::Blocks from Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 0):

The file path references, such as: obj\Debug\main.o are giving an absolute path. What you probably want is: `.\obj\Debug\main.o` so you get a relative path based on the current directory. Your Code::Blocks and gcc installations in Ubuntu 18.04 seem to be OK for C programming language, but please note that for C++ you also need to install g++ package with `sudo apt install g++`